# Build Time limitation with Hosted build agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a build definition in VSTS and triggered the build. The build shows that I have few minutes remaining. What does it mean? Is it like I can't use hosted build agent after the end of allowed free minutes.If so, then how can I continue using build definition.

Is it like, I will have to create the private agent and then queue new build?

Please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means few free minutes remaining to use Hosted agent in this month.

You can check the Hosted agent minutes used in admin page (`https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_admin/_buildQueue?_a=resourceLimits`), total free minutes is 240 minutes for a month.

You can setup a private build agent, it’s free and no time limit: [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)

You also can buy build pipelines: [How to buy more pipeline capacity for builds and releases in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/buy-more-build-vs)